# Bootstrap: change background color

Tags: css

I'm new to learning Bootstrap and I'm looking have 2 col-md-6 divs next to one another having one background-color blue and the other white. How can I change one background color and not both?

I'm trying to get a look similar to below the full width photo on this website. Minus the image on the left. I just want a block white and a block blue. http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Boxify/

CSS

```
.bg-primary {
    background-color: #1a52c6;
}
```

HTML

```
      <section class="bg-primary" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


            <!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->

  <div class="col-md-6">
  <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Title</h2>
  <p class="text-faded text-center">.col-md-6</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 blue">
  <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Title</h2>
  <p class="text-faded text-center">.col-md-6</p>
  </div>
  </div>
             </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: This isn't really a Bootstrap question but rather a CSS and HTML question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can target that div from your stylesheet in a number of ways.

Simply use

```
.col-md-6:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Another way is to assign a class to one div and then apply the style to that class.

```
<div class="col-md-6 blue"></div>

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

There are also inline styles.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: blue"></div>
```

Your example code works fine to me. I'm not sure if I undestand what you intend to do, but if you want a blue background on the second div just remove the `bg-primary` class from the section and add you custom class to the div.

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Title</h2>
        <p class="text-faded text-center">.col-md-6</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 blue">
        <h2 class="section-heading text-center">Title</h2>
        <p class="text-faded text-center">.col-md-6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hmm.. That works thank you! So I downloaded a template and was trying to adopt it to my own style. This is how my code looks, I'll update the main question.

Comment: So, where are you having the problem now?

Comment: When I use my code above, the entire section is blue. When I change the background to the divs it only works for the P and H2 tag. Should I remove the section and wrap each col-md-6 into a div with a definded bg?

Comment: Answer update. Not sure if that is what you are looking for, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could hard code it.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:blue;">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:white;">
</div>
```

Comment: This will work but I do suggest staying clear of inline-styling.

Answer (score 3):

Not Bootstrap specific really... You can use inline styles or define a custom class to specify the desired "background-color".

On the other hand, Bootstrap *does* have a few built in background colors that have semantic meaning like "bg-success" (green) and "bg-danger" (red).