# Bootstrap custom background

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm getting this.
So basically I want to change my background of a container using hover but I can't seem to get it right.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container bg-black h-25 w-25 box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box:hover{                                   
  background-color: red;                                    
  box-shadow: 5px 5px red; 
}
```

at 1st I thought I might not be selecting it right then I am getting the shadow but the background still not changing.

**Before Hover**
[image: Before Hover]

**After Hover**
[image: After Hover]

**What I tried**
I skimmed through the official documentation and even read the answers to this article [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923686/bootstrap-change-background-color) but im still stuck

any kind of help would be useful and thanks a bunch

Comment: It' could be specificity-related so have a look in the dev tools or try increasing the specificity of your rule.e.g. by changing .box to div.box. Are you applying your styles before the bootstrap css file in your cascade?

Comment: @Adam i tried *div.box:hover* and even tried to just change the background without hover and still no effect im still getting to the target class because my box-shadow is working fine. thanks for commenting.

Comment: Your code is right, no problems. Maybe timing is what causes the problem. Maybe add your whole code (as a JS fiddle or something)?

Comment: What version of `Bootstrap` are you using?

Comment: @SinisaM The tag `bootstrap-5` is already added in the question and it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour i even removed the js link its just a block with *bg-black* nothing more

Comment: I've had a quick peek in the bootstrap 5 style sheet and this is the offending line. It's not working because the buggers have used !important: "background-color: #212529 !important;"

Comment: @Adam i just put !important on my custom color and it worked. aye thanks your a life saver. i have another question is this only specific to bootstrap 5 or previous versions too?

Comment: TBH I don't know. It's probably the same in earlier versions of bootstrap.  This sort of this is really frustrating! I used to use bootstrap loads but it was always difficult to restyle. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a dig around the Bootstrap 5 css file and background colours are tagged as !important so that pretty much means most css rules won't work but we can increase the specificity a touch by using `div.your-class` and also use !important as in the following example:

```css
.container {
  color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.125rem;
}

.black {
  background-color: red !important;
}

/* we nudge the specificity of this rule up a smidge using div.classname so it now overrides the css rule in Bootstrap */
div.black-importanter {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container black bg-dark'>Nope!</div>
<div class='container black-importanter bg-dark'>Yay!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its 3am here and i would had nightmares about it. now i can sleep in peace. stay safe ✌️

Comment: Cheers my dude. You too. Peace.